# Build ffmpeg2.4.2 with android-ndk-r9b on Winx64?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Now, I have got libffmpeg.so on Android, but its size is only 4.96 kB, so obviously something went wrong, but I have no idea...

Here is my config.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TMPDIR="C:/temp"
export NDKROOT="G:/android-ndk-r9b"
PREBUILT=$NDKROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
PLATFORM=$NDKROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm
./configure --target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-version3 \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-nonfree \
--disable-stripping \
--disable-ffserver \
--enable-decoder=h264 \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-encoders \
--disable-muxers \
--disable-devices \
--disable-protocols \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-avfilter \
--disable-network \
--disable-avdevice \
--enable-cross-compile \
--cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
--cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
--extra-cflags="-fPIC -DANDROID" \
--disable-asm \
--enable-neon \
--enable-armv5te \
--extra-ldflags="-Wl,-T,$PREBUILT/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/ldscripts/armelf_linux_eabi.x -Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib
 -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/crtbegin.o

$PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/crtend.o -lc -lm -ldl"
```

What could the problem be?

What I also don't understand: we already have a makefile - why should we make android.mk once again?

Comment: There is no official procedure for building FFMPEG for Android, I think.
I was able to build on Linux as they do in this project https://github.com/dannoy/dolphin-player however it has an older FFMPEG

Comment: @Alex thanks for you advice,i`m preparing to build it on linux now,but i also want know why it didnt work on win. anyway ,thank u

Comment: I wasn't able to do it on windows, on linux the whole project compiles and works.